# BOOT_COMPLETE and ACTION_SHUTDOWN never call the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I want to catch ACTION_SHUTDOWN and BOOT_COMPLETE using BroadcastReceiver.
But it turns out both signals never trigger the BroadcastReceiver (I didn't see any log on logcat). 
Here is my source code.

I give the permission on Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and I try to register the BroadcastReceiver in both ways

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    registerReceiver(BootReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED));
    registerReceiver(ShutDownReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN));
}

<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" 
          android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the source code for BootReceiver and ShutDownReceiver are as

```
private BroadcastReceiver BootReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    private String ACTION_BOOT = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BOOT)){
            //my stuff  
            Log.d("Power", "Boot Complete");
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver ShutDownReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    private String ACTION_SHUTDOWN = "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {
            //my stuff
            Log.d("Power", "Shutdown Complete");
        }
    }
};
```

also, I unregister both BoradcastReceiver in onDestroy

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    unregisterReceiver(BootReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(ShutDownReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?
Or anything I miss? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out why it didn't work.
Since I use a HTC device, the broadcast messages are different from others.

1. Shut down event broadcasts "`com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF`"
2. Restart(reboot) event broadcasts "`android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`"
3. Power on event broadcasts "`com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON`"

In other device, when shutting down the device, it might broadcast "`android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF`".

Comment: how you get to know about HTC specific intent ? I am working with micromax do you anything about it? Thanks for your answer

Comment: More secure way write following way:

private final String ACTION_SHUTDOWN = "ACTION_SHUTDOWN";
intent.getAction().contains(ACTION_SHUTDOWN)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your application is not yet added to the "BOOT_COMPLETED" possible receivers list, starting from Android 3.1, in order to get the "BOOT_COMPLETED" action, your application must have been started explicitly by the user, either showing an Activity or another Component, until then your application will not receive the broadcast you are expecting, is important to know that if you "Force Close" the application, it will be missing the broadcasts again, So, try to open an activity and then reboot your device, you will get it...

Hope this Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I activated the Acitivity myself and then reboot my device. And it turned out the same.

Comment: Look at CommonsWare answer, you must have your Receiver declared in the manifest to listen for broadcast without having the application fully running, in your code your registerReceiver method never gets to be executed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <receiver
            android:name="packagename.GPSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: AFAIK, that `android:permission` element will not work.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOT_COMPLETED` must be registered in the manifest. You cannot register for it via `registerReceiver()`, because by the time you call `registerReceiver()`, the boot will have long since occurred.

AFAIK the shutdown broadcast works with `registerReceiver()`, though in your case it will only be around when your process is running.

Comment: I also can't see any log when shutting down the device. Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: @user3138776: I have never tried to use `ACTION_SHUTDOWN`, so I have no idea what to expect. Make sure that you are truly powering down the device, though -- `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is not just for the screen turning off (that's `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`).